# Quantum numbers for Landau levels

Tags: magnetic-fields

In the presence of a magnetic field, the momentum of a charge particle changes from $p_{i}$ to $\pi_{i}\equiv p_{i}+eA_{i}$, where $e$ is the charge of the particle.

It is also possible to define another kind of momentum $\tilde{\pi}_{i}=p_{i}-eA_{i}$.

---

For a two-dimensional system with a magnetic field pointing in the $z$-direction, we can work in the symmetric gauge

$${\bf{A}}=\left(-\frac{yB}{2},\frac{xB}{2},0\right),$$

and define two sets of creation and annihilation operators $a, a^{\dagger}$ and $b, b^{\dagger}$ such that a generic state of the system is given by

$$|n,m\rangle=\frac{a^{\dagger n}b^{\dagger}n}{\sqrt{n!m!}}|0,0\rangle,$$

where $|0,0\rangle$ is the unique ground state annihilated by both $a$ and $b$.

---

$|0,0\rangle$ is the unique ground state annihilated by both $a$ and $b$ since $\pi_{i}$ and $\tilde{\pi}_{i}$ commute in the complex plane defined by $(z=x-iy,\bar{z}=x+iy)$ and commuting observables have a common basis of eigenfunctions.

Does this not mean that the quantum numbers labelled by $n$ and $m$ give the same wavefunctions?

Why does the energy of the state depend only on $n$, but not on $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hamiltonian is $H = \frac{1}{2m}\boldsymbol{\pi}^2$. Hence the energy is related to the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{\pi}$. We also know that $[\tilde{\boldsymbol{\pi}}, H] = 0$, so that states can be labeled by energy level $n$ and eigenstates of $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\pi}}$ simultaneously. In other words, $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\pi}}$ describes the degeneracy at a given energy level $n$; only $n$ controls energy, and $m$ describes an "orthogonal" degeneracy space.

Different states $|n,m\rangle$ are be described by different wavefunctions. In the lowest Landau level $n=0$, the value $m$ describes the angular momentum of the wavefunction, and in symmetric gauge control the "radius" of the wavefunction.

[Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html) describe this pretty clearly, in my opinion, so it might be helpful to you.

Comment: If $\tilde{\pi}$ and $H$ commute, this means that they have the same wavefunctions. The wavefunctions of $H$ are labelled by $n$, so the states can be labelled by $n$ and eigenstates of $\tilde{\pi}$ simultaneously. I get that. But I don't see why this means that $\tilde{\pi}$ describes the degeneracy at a given energy level $n$. After all, if there are $n$ energy levels, then there must be $n$ eigenstates of $\tilde{\pi}$ (one for each value of $n$) and not more than one eigenstate of $\tilde{\pi}$ for a given value of $n$!

Comment: @failexam No, there can be more than one eigenstate for each $n$. For example, take the case of a free electron ($H= \frac{p^2}{2m}$) with momentum $p$ and spin $J$. Clearly $[S_z, H] = 0$. Hence for each energy level $n$, there corresponds a spin-up and a spin-down state, $2$ for each energy level. The eigenvalues of spin are determined independent of the energy eigenvalues. In the same way, the eigenvalues $m$ are determined independently from $n$.